How can I disable iOS from changing what I type into another, longer word without losing suggestions above the keyboard?
After a recent update of iOS, the keyboard started acting possessed and turns my sentences into something totally different.
If I type:
How long ago was that?

When I look at my sentence it says:
How long agony was that?

If I type:
Thanks for your help!

The keyboard types:
Thanksgiving for your help!

And if I ever mistype it gets worse, when:
Thanks gor that!

turns into:
Thanks gorgeous that!

I would love to revert my settings to a time when I had suggestions of words the OS was assuming I was trying to type displayed right above the keyboard, and not have to deal with these usually erroneous assumptions of what I'm trying to type.
But I feel like it's either no suggestions at all, or everything being replaced by the OS's assumption.
What settings should I change?

Doesn't the algorithm work on basing suggestions on your previous inputs? So when, in some apps, you type slang or colloquial text that then carries over into apps where you would tend to be using more elegant speech giving you erroneous suggestions...

You should disable spellcheck & autocorrect in general -> keyboard

@SolarMike In my experience, this is either false or broken in my case. Random words I never use show up (like how often do people use "thanksgiving" versus "thanks"? Shouldn't using thanks prevail instead of filling it out into a longer word?) Or French words show up as suggestions in the English keyboard, but not in the French one like - and show up when typing less letters too! As here https://imgur.com/a/PI0mCuX

@hym3242 Ok so disabling spell check seems to work - for some reason when I tried that before the suggestions atop the keyboard would disappear - make your comment into an answer so I can accept it? I was going crazy having to use the text replacement feature to counteract the autocomplete feature... like I literally had a text replacement where "thanksgiving" was replaced with "Thanks" and it made my devices work funny

That's nice to hear. You may want to edit the question title to something more descriptive and accurate. What do you mean by "for some reason when I tried that before the suggestions atop the keyboard would disappear"?

@hym3242 I thought I had tried disabling these two features before, but I could never remove the feature that completes words with a longer word (ago > agony) without losing the bar above the keyboard with the typing suggestions.

@hym3242 These are my current settings and the problem is actually still there https://imgur.com/a/WTHYE7O

You can disable spellcheck and/or autocorrect in System Settings -> General -> Keyboard.

These are my settings but the problem is still therehttps://imgur.com/a/WTHYE7O
